# query cache and buffer pool not able to help, lot of tables are created on disk

Tags: mysql, performance, caching, query-cache

I am running a self-coded PHP-MySQL site and have enable query cache with below configuration.

```
query_cache_type = 1
query_cache_size = 20M
query_cache_limit = 4096
query_cache_min_res_unit = 4096

tmp_table_size = 512M
max_heap_table_size = 512M
```

I am able to read above configuration as:

- query cache is enabled
- don't cache queries whose result size is more than 4096 bytes
- total queries that can be accommodate in buffer is around 5000 query results (20MB/4KB = 5000)

I don't understand how **tmp_table_size** or **max_heap_table_size** are going to be helpful to query cache. These variables are related to temporary tables created in memory or on disk (if required).

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 4G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 4
```

System has 32GB memory, where almost 50% memory is empty most of time. So I have set **innodb_buffer_pool_size** to 4G. Database size is around 900MB and growing around 2MB per day.

I am getting following output with mysqltuner utility

```
Key buffer hit rate: 69.3%
Temporary tables created on disk: 75%
Query cache efficiency: 5.9%
```

Looks like I have set some wrong configuration. Let me know what should be improved.

Answer (score 0):

Temp tables (for `SELECTs`) end up on disks for multiple reasons:

- The `SELECT` list includes a `TEXT` or `BLOB` column (or large `VARCHAR` or `VARBINARY`)
- The tmp table is bigger than either of `tmp_table_size` or `max_heap_table_size`.

The "Query cache" is a different animal.  First note that it is useful only when

- The *identical* `SELECT` is being performed, *and*
- *No* writes have modified the table(s) since the `SELECT` resultset was cached, *and*
- Various limits (like what you mentioned) have not been exceeded.

Note `Query cache efficiency: 5.9%` -- the QC is not very useful for you.  I would argue for turning it off.  (I would turn it off if this is below, say, 70%.)

Creating tmp tables on disk is not the end of the world.

```
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;
```

Then `Created_tmp_disk_tables/Uptime` is informative.  Maybe only 10% of servers have a value of zero.  80% have a value of less than 1/second.  How *often* are you creating tmp tables on disk?

Probably mysqltuner is computing this:

```
Created_tmp_disk_tables / (Created_tmp_disk_tables + Created_tmp_tables)
```

In which case, I will agree that 75% is really high.  2% would be desirable.

`Key buffer hit rate: 69.3%` is talking about MyISAM indexing.  Are you using MyISAM or InnoDB?  If you are using MyISAM, what is the value of `key_buffer_size`?  It could be that this is irrelevant -- there is a small amount of MyISAM activity for admin purposes.

Back to the *real* question -- You want to speed up slow queries.  Let's see some query that is probably spilling to disk, plus the `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  It could be some simple fix.

If you would like a more thorough analysis of your settings, please provide a machine readable version of `SHOW VARIABLES;` and `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;`.